# Slowdown Crowdin when using ICU

Tags: translation, icu, crowdin

When I create a big key with ICU syntax, Crowdin becomes really slow after some unknown quantity of icu-elements in the key. And it doesn’t slow down Crowdin in general, it freezes the platform only when you choose this key and try to do something with it.

The temporary solution was dividing the key into two. But it’s a bad decision.

Key example:

> We’ve automatically applied the discount to your {contextTrial,
> select, day{{countTrial, plural, one{#-day} other{#-day} }}
> week{{countTrial, plural, one{#-week} other{#-week} }}
> month{{countTrial, plural, one{#-month} other{#-month} }}
> year{{countTrial, plural, one{#-year} other{#-year} }}
> other{{countTrial, plural, one{#-period} other{#-period} }}} trial
> price. Please note that your subscription will be automatically
> renewed at the full price of {currencySign}{fullPrice} per {context,
> select, day{{count, plural, one{# day} other{# days} }} week{{count,
> plural, one{# week} other{# weeks} }} month{{count, plural, one{#
> month} other{# months} }} year{{count, plural, one{# year} other{#
> years} }} other{{count, plural, one{# period} other{# periods} }}} at
> the end of your trial and will then be continuously renewed every
> {context, select, day{{count, plural, one{# day} other{# days} }}
> week{{count, plural, one{# week} other{# weeks} }} month{{count,
> plural, one{# month} other{# months} }} year{{count, plural, one{#
> year} other{# years} }} other{{count, plural, one{# period} other{#
> periods} }}} until you cancel via {domain}